# 'Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory' in component linking

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

We are getting Java.Lang.RuntimeException error in all the website pages. Following is the snippet from the cd_core log.

I have seen the license file has been commented out from storage config. Could it be a reason? Or is it the cd_linking.jar not available in the lib?

```
2013-12-04 01:00:35,496 ERROR ComponentLink - Error while constructing linking: Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
    at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.init(ComponentLink.java:124) ~[cd_linking.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.<init>(ComponentLink.java:86) [cd_linking.jar:na]
2013-12-04 01:00:35,496 ERROR ComponentLink - No LinkInfo is found in the bindings, could not retrieve ComponentLinkInfo
```

**UPDATE 1 -** As I said, the licence file is commented out.

```
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="sessionDb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
  <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" /> 
- <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
  <Property Name="serverName" Value="abc" /> 
  <Property Name="portNumber" Value="test123" /> 
  <Property Name="databaseName" Value="testdb" /> 
  <Property Name="user" Value="testuser" /> 
  <Property Name="password" Value="test" /> 
  </DataSource>
  </Storage>
  </Wrapper>
  </Wrappers>
- <Storages>
- <Storage Type="persistence" Id="TridionDB" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
  <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" /> 
- <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
  <Property Name="serverName" Value="xyz" /> 
  <Property Name="portNumber" Value="test" /> 
  <Property Name="databaseName" Value="testdb1" /> 
  <Property Name="user" Value="testuser1" /> 
  <Property Name="password" Value="testpwd" /> 
  </DataSource>
  </Storage>
- <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="LocalFileSystem" defaultStorage="true" LocalFileSystemsystem="false">
  <Root Path="b:/root/path" /> 
  </Storage>
- <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="LocalFileSystemData">
  <Root Path="c:/root/path" /> 
  </Storage>
  </Storages>
  </Global>
- <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="TridionDB">
- <!-- 
    <Item typeMapping="Publication" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Asp" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="BinaryMeta" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="BinaryVariant" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentMeta" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentationMeta" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="ItemMeta" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Jsp" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="LinkInfo" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="PageMeta" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="Reference" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="Schema" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="XSLT" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Txt" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Xml" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="Page" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="LocalFileSystem" />

  --> 
  </ItemTypes>
- <!-- 
 Specifies the location of the license file. 
    <License Location="cd_licenses.xml"/>
  --> 
UPDATE 2 - 
<! --DD4T-->  
<Publication  Id="42" d efaultStorageId="Tri dionDB" cached="fale">    
<Item  storageId ="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary" cached="true"  />
```

Comment: are there any other warnings or errors before this in your logfile.
Could you also post your storage config file. You should off course also make sure all of the necessary jar files are in your lib folder (check the install documentation)

Comment: The error mentions lines 124 and 86 of `ComponentLink.java` so your `cd_linking.jar` is definitely found. But it could not initialize class `com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory` so it seems you have an error in your storage `cd_storage_conf.xml`, could you edit your question and add your Storages and ItemTypes configuration?

Comment: I have updated the storage config in my question.

Comment: Have you updated or changed the Java version recently?  I have found that NoClassDefFoundError is usually related to java not behaving well on the system.

Comment: I need to ask as we don't have access to test box.

Comment: @Bart, is there any issue in the storage file?

Comment: @user833 I'm assuring this is the `cd_storage_conf.xml` from your staging website (seeing the SessionWrapper storage part in there) it doesn;t appear directly wrong, provided the Storage configuration of your Deployer is pointing to the same locations.

Comment: Yes, I have asked for the deployer storage. The license file is commented, would it be a problem ?

Comment: That is not valid XML that you've pasted there. Is that an exact copy from the file? If so, it's no wonder you are getting that error :) If it's just a paste error to StackExchange, could you update it with a copy directly from the file (i.e. open it in a text editor)?
As an example, it has a bunch of "-" signs next to some elements and it's missing the end Configuration tag.

Comment: I have checked the website and deployer's storage and both are pointing to the same db. Also found the DD4T entries(given in UPDATE 2 in my original question) with wrong pub id. Could it be a reason?

Comment: Our website is non-DD4T and the publication id of some DD4T website is specified in this website's storage which is non-DD4T.

Comment: As Peter says: can you check if your XML is actually valid?

Answer (score 5):

I have received this error earlier when automatic update of JDK have corrupted my existing java installation.

Just go to the command line on the server and execute `java -version` command and verify whether the installed java is correct version and is working perfectly fine.

If after executing the `java -version` command you receive `NoClassDefFoundError` error, manually un-install and re-install java on your server.

Do this for both 32-bit as well as 64-bit installations.

Comment: we have other websites hosted on the same server as this site. Shouldn't it impact all the sites running in the same Java installation? I am asking this as the other sites are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as the comment above. 
But i'm recommending to setup a single location for the license file and then point to it from all the places where it's needed. 
In your case, open up cd_link_conf.xml and add this just before the < Configuration/>:

```
<License Location="C:/Your/path/cd_licenses.xml"/>
```

Comment: If you add that line to your configs, is it safe to remove the cd_licenses.xml file from everywhere except that centralized location?

Comment: Well, i depends, if you add this line in all your tridion config files you will rely on that centralized one!

Answer (score 1):

This could also be a simple missing JAR problem.

The error is a bit confusing, but it could be that class `com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory` can't be found. Make sure you have JAR `cd_datalayer.jar` among your other JARs in the `/lib` folder.

You don't have to have the `License` node in your config, as long as there is a `cd_licenses.xml` file in your `/classes` folder (or somewhere in your classpath).

Comment: cd_datalayer.jar is present in the website. Actually the Storage configuration of the Deployer is pointing to a diff location from the website. I have asked to make the website's storage in sync with deployer. Will update further.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error But in a different scenario and I figured out that my cd_license was expired.

**So for once do validate your cd_license.xml.**

This might fix your problem.